# How to replace allocators of stl with actual source code

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, portable-executable, allocator

I need to replace allocators with their original source code. I am extracting exported methods from the PE export table and facing strange lengthy allocators where STL containers were used in the original source code. i.e. If source code was:

```
   typedef std::list<std::basic_string<_TCHAR> > TokenList;
   EXPORTS_API const TokenList& getLiteralList( );
```

from the export table I am getting:

```
std::list<class std::basic_string<unsigned short, std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class
 std::allocator<unsigned short> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<unsigned 
short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > > > 
const & __thiscall CExpressionTokenizer::getLiteralList(void)
```

How do I get the backtrack from the above lengthy allocators to its original source code? (typedefs increase more in size.)

Regards,

Usman

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean that you want to be able to determine a more succinct type name from the export table. The standard allocator (`std::allocator`) is the default template parameter for allocator parameter in most standard container class templates so you can just remove the entire allocator parameter from the template specialization to come up with a simpler expression of the same type.

E.g.

```
std::list<class std::basic_string<unsigned short, std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class
std::allocator<unsigned short> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<unsigned 
short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > > > 
const & __thiscall CExpressionTokenizer::getLiteralList(void)
```

becomes

```
std::list<class std::basic_string<unsigned short, std::char_traits<unsigned short> > > 
const & __thiscall CExpressionTokenizer::getLiteralList(void)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about decoding the error messages? Try [STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html).

Comment: I thought that at first too, but as far as I can tell he's got a utility that extracts names from an executable. Those names are riddled with allocator stuff (as they should be), and he wants to get rid of them, I think.

Comment: yeah definetly.
I want to have exact replacement of my original source code in place of those allocators stuff. Actually I need to show these types and extracted methods(Which I taken from export table)at GUI or say some XMLs. So as user I won't be recognize these allocators

Comment: You can't have an exact replacement. Allocators in STL containers are just one example of default arguments. E.g. `std::set<T>` will also have a `std::less<T>` default order. After compiling, you can't figure out anymore whether a default argument was provided or not. That's not to mention typedefs (`std::string` is really `std::basic_string<char>` )

Comment: So what actually the solution of above statted problem..?
I need not exact replacement of typedefs names which actually are in the code. How to eliminate or replace those allocators stuff with actual STL written code?